# Problema ejecutando npm install -g @angular/cli

Tags: nodejs, angular

Estoy tratando de iniciar mi primer proyecto en angular y todavía no puedo instalarlo, cuando hago un "npm install -g @angular/cli" en una carpeta del escritorio me aparecen los siguientes errors y warnings, [image: mas abajo sigo el hilo contra captura]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

[image: segunda parte de la captura]

No comprendo cual sea el problema pero si la comunidad me puede dar una mano estaré más que feliz de aceptar sus consejos.
Saludos.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Si tienes algo adicional que comentar, nuevas cosas que incluir o respuestas a comentarios, puedes [edit] tu pregunta todas las veces que sea necesario. Abajo el campo se titula _Tu Respuesta_ y no es para usarlo como un foro. Si intentaste algo con nvm y salió otra cosa, indícalo en la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Posiblemente puede ser por tu antivirus que bloquean algunos archivos al momento de instalar. Tendrías que desactivarlo y volver a instalar tus paquetes. Me dices si te funcionó.

Comment: Hola Cris, me recomendaron instalar nvm para instalar la version que quiera de node js, estoy teniendo problemas con esto tambien, no tengo anti virus así que no creo que sea por eso, mi problema se origino al instalar la ultima version de node js con el comando "nvm install node" y el warning es Warning: Failed to open the file                                               
Warning: /home/leo/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v18.9.0-linux-x64/node-v18.9.0-linux-x6
Warning: 4.tar.xz: Permission denied

Comment: haz la instalación con permisos de administrador `sudo npm install...`

Comment: Dale una revisada a la seguridad de tu sistema operativo, puede que algo esté bloqueando la instalación de tus paquetes.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer, tu antivirus esta bloqueando los archivos. Puedes intentar resolver esto usando

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

o ejecuta la consola con **permisos de administrador**

En caso de que esto no funcioné, pausa tu antivirus mientras haces la instalación.

Answer (score 0):

Tenes que actualizar node
Mejor forma  de actualizar Node.js en Linux y macOS es NVM
Usando comandos :

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
```

o

```
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
```

Luego

```
nvm install node
```

luego

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```